# why does my image show as an error on a live server

Tags: html, image, path

### Problem

So I have an error image in my live server. Any help would be much appreciated.

### Images

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOzIZ.png)
[liveserver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrvNK.png)

### What I have tried

- I've checked the path
- Re-downloaded the files
- tried moving the files so create a shorter path.
- checked the code of the `<img>`
- check css incase of implications,
- validated both to check for bugs everything seems to be correct.
- ive tried on multiple browers.
- cleared my cache.

I'm probably over looking something but I cant figure out what it is.

Comment: fixed with ./Assets/logo/ohmyfood.png

for some reason
/dist/Assets/logo/ohmyfood.png 
was showing as  
dist/dist/Assets/logo/ohmyfood.png

Comment: The hourly "why doesn't my image show" question.

Answer (score 1):

If `/dist/` directory is in root of your project, try set `src` tag to `/dist/Assets/logo/ohmyfood.png`, it may be because of incorrect relative link